# How to store a hashed password in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, sha

I am trying to store a hashed password in SQL Server 2008 R2 but when I compare the stored version with original they do not match.

```
string password = "12345";
User user = new User();
user.USERNAME = "JohnDoe";

using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
            rngCsp.GetBytes(salt);
            user.SALT = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(salt);
}

using (SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    user.PASSWORD = UTF32Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sha.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + user.SALT)));
}

//store the user on db
db.UserUpdate(user);

// now get the db values that have been saved and compare with original
var userOnDB = db.UsersGet(user.USERNAME);
var passwordOnDb = userOnDB.PASSWORD;

//this returns false
if (passwordOnDb == user.PASSWORD)
{

}
```

The SQL Server table has the columns:

```
TABLE [dbo].[USERS]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SALT] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PASSWORD] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    .........
)
```

This is my DB access code:

```
public USER UsersGet(string userName)
{
        using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            return ctx.USERS.Where(a => a.USERNAME == userName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}

public void UserUpdate(USER user)
{
    try
    {
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                if (controller.ID == 0)
                {
                    ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is my `User` object

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string FIRSTNAME { get; set; }
public string LASTNAME { get; set; }
public string ADDRESS1 { get; set; }
public string ADDRESS2 { get; set; }
public string ADDRESS3 { get; set; }
public string TOWN { get; set; }
public string POCODE { get; set; }
public string MOBILE { get; set; }
public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
public bool ACTIVE { get; set; }
public string NIC { get; set; }
public string LANDLINE { get; set; }
public string USERNAME { get; set; }
public string EMAIL { get; set; }
public string SALT { get; set; }
public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
```

So I thought I must have wrong column types in SQL Server table.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with passwords, hashes, salt or data types.  You simply have a bug in either how you read or write the data to the database, but we have no details on that part of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the password hash to match you need to use the salt saved in the database not create a new one

Comment: I believe that the Salt is only created once then stored with the user then then immediately retrieved and compared.

Comment: ok Assuming that is true on is the user linked to the password if the table only has 2 columns password and salt?

Comment: Have edited to take out some of the stuff not relevent  and included the  SQL table

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the UserUpdate function and make sure the Id is not zero.  I suspect you have a bunch of records for the user name